# Parallel consumption of asyncSeq using BlockingQueueAgent

Tags: asynchronous, f#, parallel-processing, async-workflow

Time to embarrass myself again with a lack of understanding of how concurrency works in .NET :P

I'm trying to write a function that can encapsulates creating an async workflow that takes an asyncSeq input and distributes it to n parallel consumers.

```
let doWorkInParallel bufferSize numberOfConsumers consumer input = async {
    let buffer = BlockingQueueAgent<_>(bufferSize)
    let inputFinished = ref false

    let produce seq = async {
        do! seq |> AsyncSeq.iterAsync (Some >> buffer.AsyncAdd)
        do! buffer.AsyncAdd None
    }

    let consumeParallel degree f = async {
        let consume f = async {
            while not <| !inputFinished do
                try
                    let! data = buffer.AsyncGet(waitTimeout)
                    match data with
                    | Some i -> do! f i
                    // whichever consumer gets the end of the input flips the inputFinished ref so they'll all stop processing
                    | None -> inputFinished := true
                with | :? TimeoutException -> ()
        }

        do! [for slot in 1 .. degree -> consume f ]
            |> Async.Parallel
            |> Async.Ignore
    }

    let startProducer = produce input
    let startConsumers = consumeParallel numberOfConsumers consumer

    return! [| startProducer; startConsumers |] |> Async.Parallel |> Async.Ignore
}
```

and I've been testing it with code like this to simulate a sequence that's fast to create but the work for each item takes a while.

```
let input = seq {1..50} |> AsyncSeq.ofSeq
let action i = async {
    do! Async.Sleep 500
    printfn "%d GET" i
    }
let test = doWorkInParallel 10 2 action input
Async.RunSynchronously test
```

EDIT: I seem to have fixed my initial problems (ugh, I REALLY didn't think about what I was doing with an EventWaitHandle, so silly), but I'd still love to hear if this is a totally stupid approach to the problem with F#.

Comment: I have a feeling that I'm barking up the completely wrong tree and should be looking at PLINQ instead for work like this.

Comment: Or [Reactive Extensions](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/Rx.NET/)

Comment: Yeah, I figured Rx wasn't a good fit for this (it's push-based, I want pull-based).

Comment: I think Parallel.Foreach().WithDegreeOfParallelism() may save you quite some work here, like you added in your comment.

Comment: Would it be possible to support cancellation with the Parallel.Foreach() style?